# Процент числа Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, форматирование, проценты

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, мне нужно было узнать сколько `30%` от числа `0.000175`.

Написал я `0.000175 / 100 * 30`, а python говорит что это `5.25е-05`, но это не `30%`, если делать это через калькулятор, то выходит `0.0000525`.

Либо это я тупой и ничего не понимаю либо тут что-то не так.

Comment: "5.25е-05" это по-вашему сколько?

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C

Comment: "{0:0.7f}".format(0.000175 / 100 * 30)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Выводите значение в строку через форматирование с указанным количеством знаков после запятой (в данном примере 10 знаков)

```
print('{:.10f}'.format(0.000175 / 100 * 30))  # '0.0000525000'
print(f'{0.000175 / 100 * 30:.10f}')          # '0.0000525000'
```

Если не нравятся дополнительные `0` из-за большой точности, то можно их убрать (костылем):

```
value = '{:.10f}'.format(0.000175 / 100 * 30)
print(value)              # '0.0000525000'
print(value.rstrip('0'))  # '0.0000525'
```

Точность можно не указывать, но тогда может быть округление, как в примере ниже:

```
value = '{:f}'.format(0.000175 / 100 * 30)
print(value)  # '0.000053'
```

Answer (score 1):

5.25е-05 = 5.25 * 10^-5 = 0.0000525

Если вам сложно понимать такое представление чисел, то изучите форматирование. [Источник.](https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/formatirovanie-strok-operator.html)

```
print( '%f!' % (0.000175 / 100 * 30) )
```

Таким образом вы сможете получить вывод в той форме, которая вам требуется. Но изучить [экспоненциальную запись](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C) также полезно, с ней ваш код будет выглядеть более солидно)

Answer (score 0):

С дробными, целыми и знаком `/` нужно быть аккуратней.

```
print 100/3
33
```

Обратитесь к модулю `decimal` или например можно заменить знак деления на умножение и степень, в этом случае работает корректно:

```
print 0.000175 *(100)**-1 * 30
# 5.25e-05

print '{:.7f}'.format(0.000175 *(100)**-1 * 30)
# '0.0000525'
```

Comment: У автора python3, поэтому `print 100/3` не будет работать, а в питоне3 оператор `/` выполняет делением с остатком, поэтому `print(100/3)  # 33.333333333333336`